# How to handle multiple alarms in Broadcast receiver Android Kotlin

Tags: android, notifications, kotlin, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

My exercise app allows the user to create multiple notification alerts to prompt them to exercise. I am using a TimePickerDialog to set the alarms. I am adding the details of the alarms to the AlarmReceivers Intent using a bundle. After researching this on StackO I think I have to use different Pending intents with different request codes in order to have multiple alarms.

My question is how do I know in AlarmReceiver which pending intent has caused onReceive? Can I use the request code of the pending intent to determine which one it was? Having an id in the intent bundle doesn't help because it could contain both alarm extras.

Thanks in advance if you can explain how this should work....

```
class TimePickerFragment : DialogFragment(), TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

lateinit var alarmManager: AlarmManager
val intent = Intent(activity, AlarmReceiver::class.java)
val bundle = Bundle()

override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {

    // use the current time as default values for the picker
    val c = Calendar.getInstance()
    val hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
    val minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)

    // create a new instance of the TimePicker dialogue and return it
    return TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
            DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity())
            )
override fun onTimeSet(view: TimePicker, hourOfDay: Int, minute: Int) {

    val mTag = tag
    if (mTag == "time1") {

        // add alarm to the intent bundle
        bundle.putString("Alarm1", "This is the ${hourOfDay}:${minute} alert")
        intent.putExtras(bundle)
        setAlarm(hourOfDay,minute,intent, 1) //request code 1
    }

   if (mTag == "time2") {
        // add alarm to the intent bundle
        bundle.putString("Alarm2", "This is the ${hourOfDay}:${minute} alert")
        intent.putExtras(bundle)
        setAlarm(hourOfDay,minute,intent, 2) //request code 2
    }
}

fun setAlarm(hourOfDay: Int, minute: Int, intent: Intent, requestCode: Int) {

    alarmManager = activity.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.activity, requestCode, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay)
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute)
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.timeInMillis, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent)
}
```

And in AlarmReceiver class:

```
class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() 

{override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {

        val intent = Intent(context, AlarmReceiver::class.java)
        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

        val pendingIntent = val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT) 
// HOW TO TEST WHICH PENDING INTENT THIS IS?
```

Comment: I don't understand your broadcast receiver, is intent passed to `onReceive` useless since you never read it?

Comment: if i can work out which pendingIntent caused onReceive then I can get the correct extras from the intent.